# React native- ios and android box shadow

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native development. I am trying to make the design in the image below:

[image]

How can I achieve the box affect? I was trying with box shadow but I was not getting the correct look. It looks like the 'box' is indented into the screen and the cards scroll underneath it. Has anyone ever done something like this? Or can you point me in the right direction?

This is my code for my home screen:

```
  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingComponent />
  ) : (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={Layout.fill}>
        <View style={[Layout.alignItemsStart, Gutters.largeTMargin, Gutters.largeLMargin]}>
          <Text style={common.headingTextStyle}>{welcomeUser}</Text>
          <Text style={[Gutters.regularTMargin, common.subHeadingTextStyle]}>Available</Text>
        </View>
        <SafeAreaView
          style={[
            Layout.fill,
            Layout.center,
            // styles.jobsBox,
            Gutters.regularHMargin,
            Gutters.regularVMargin,
          ]}
        >
          <ScrollView
            style={[
              Layout.fullSize,
              Gutters.regularLPadding,
              Gutters.regularRPadding,
              Gutters.largeBMargin,
            ]}
          >
            {_.map(jobs, (job) => (
              <Job jobData={job} key={_.get(job, 'id')} />
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Platform module from react-native to conditionally set shadow styles based on the platform, and then vary between `elevation` for Android and `shadowColor`, `shadowOffset`, `shadowOpacity`, and `shadowRadius` for IOS.

Here is a step by step:

#### 1. **Understanding Platform-Specific Shadow Properties:**

- React Native offers different shadow properties for iOS and Android due to platform differences.
- For iOS, use properties like **`shadowColor`**, **`shadowOffset`**, **`shadowOpacity`**, and **`shadowRadius`**.
- For Android, the **`elevation`** property creates a shadow effect.

#### 2. **Creating a Custom Component:**

- Start by creating a custom component that accepts additional styles for box shadow.
- Use the **`Platform`** module from **`react-native`** to conditionally set shadow styles based on the platform.

#### 3. **Implementation Steps:**

#### **Step 1: Import Necessary Modules**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
```

****Step 2: Define the Custom Component****

```
const BoxShadowComponent = () => {
  // Platform-specific shadow properties
  const boxShadow = Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? {
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 2,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 3.84,
      }
    : {
        elevation: 5,
      };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.box, boxShadow]} />
  );
};
```

****Step 3: Define Styles****

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  box: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 8,
    margin: 16,
  },
});
```

****Step 4: Use the Custom Component****

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BoxShadowComponent />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
  },
});
```

#### 4. **Notes:**

- Adjust the **`boxShadow`** variable to match your preferred shadow configuration (color, offset, opacity, radius, etc.).
- Apply the **`boxShadow`** style within your custom component's styles or merge it with other styles as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Shadows in react native are tricky particularly because of android. However there are 2 great libraries that can help you with making shadows using CSS format, and cross platform. [react native shadow 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow-2) and [react native drop shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drop-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

The best library I tried is [react native neomorph shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-neomorph-shadows) and its cross-platform library:

```
import { Shadow } from 'react-native-neomorph-shadows';
 
...
 
{_.map(jobs, (job) => (<Shadow
  inner // <- enable inner shadow
  useArt // <- set this prop to use non-native shadow on ios
  style={{
    shadowOffset: {width: 10, height: 10},
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowColor: "grey",
    shadowRadius: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    // ...include most of View/Layout styles
  }}
>
  <Job jobData={job} key={_.get(job, 'id')} />
</Shadow>)}
```

Comment: where exactly whoul you place the <Shadow> ? I will update my question with my code

Comment: Wrap your View with it.

Comment: I have attempted to do the shadow. I installed "react-native-neomorph-shadows": "^1.1.2", and  "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",.  But I am geeing an error saying:   TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[10], "./helpers").extractOpacity') aswell as Requiring module "node_modules/@react-native-community/art/lib/helpers.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.hex')

Comment: This is a common issue you can check this video on how to create a patch for the library and fix it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrDBJxIyjac

Answer (score 0):

Try the below shadow style-

```
shadow: {
    borderColor: color.palette.warmGrey,
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    shadowColor: color.palette.black,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 3,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.27,
    shadowRadius: 4.65,
    elevation: 3,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: color.palette.white,
  },
```

Comment: This work only on IOS.

Comment: I found it working on both android and ios. Anyway, Did you find any solution?

Comment: On Android, only the `elevation` property work. `react-native-neomorph-shadows` can do it.